# Mountain Lion installer doesnt start after reboot

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, install, macos

I am currently trying to install Mountain Lion and everything was going fine until it was time to reboot.

First I tried rebooting then it said i needed to close applications so I clicked the button to close applications and it hung for a few minutes then the installer crashed so I ran the installer again as it didnt restart on its own after clicking reopen application.
The installer immediately gave me the restart button as im assuming the file caching process was completed. Now, whenever I click the restart button it just restarts my macbook and the installer never kicks in. I've done this around 4-5 times now exact same thing each time.

I'm not sure if there are corrupt files in the installer cache or its sending the wrong reboot message but i havent been able to install it one way or another. any ideas?

**Edit:**

did a disk repair and permissions repair and turned off file vault still have same issues

the installer log after installation failed

```
Jul 28 04:00:04 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: opendirectoryd (build 197.11.16) launched - installer mode
Jul 28 04:00:04 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: Logging level limit changed to 'notice'
Jul 28 04:00:05 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: Initialize trigger support
Jul 28 04:00:05 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: created endpoint for mach service 'com.apple.private.opendirectoryd.rpc' with work limit 10
Jul 28 04:00:05 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: set default handler for RPC 'reset_cache'
Jul 28 04:00:05 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: set default handler for RPC 'reset_statistics'
Jul 28 04:00:05 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: set default handler for RPC 'show'
Jul 28 04:00:05 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: starting endpoint for service 'com.apple.private.opendirectoryd.rpc'
Jul 28 04:00:05 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: no dynamic data found at '/System/Library/OpenDirectory/DynamicData/Configure.plist'
Jul 28 04:00:05 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: Registered node with name '/Configure' as hidden
Jul 28 04:00:05 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: no dynamic data found at '/System/Library/OpenDirectory/DynamicData/Local.plist'
Jul 28 04:00:05 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: Registered node with name '/Local' as hidden
Jul 28 04:00:09 localhost Unknown[312]: kern.boottime: { sec = 1343473200, usec = 0 } Sat Jul 28 04:00:00 2012
Jul 28 04:00:09 localhost Unknown[320]: Launching the Language Chooser for an OS Install
Jul 28 04:00:16 localhost Unknown[322]: 2012-07-28 04:00:16.231 LCA[321:707] NSSoftLinking - The Librarian framework's library couldn't be loaded from (null).
Jul 28 04:00:16 localhost Unknown[322]: 2012-07-28 04:00:16.233 LCA[321:707] NSSoftLinking - The function 'LBCurrentProcessHasUbiquityContainer' can't be found in the Librarian framework.
Jul 28 04:00:16 localhost configd[112]: bootp_session_transmit: bpf_write(en1) failed: Network is down (50)
Jul 28 04:00:16 localhost configd[112]: DHCP en1: INIT transmit failed
Jul 28 04:00:19 localhost Unknown[322]: 2012-07-28 04:00:19.578 LCA[321:707] LCA+BT2: systemHasBluetooth entry
Jul 28 04:00:19 localhost Unknown[322]: 2012-07-28 04:00:19.579 LCA[321:707] LCA+BT2: [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] processName] LCA
Jul 28 04:00:19 localhost Unknown[322]: 2012-07-28 04:00:19.579 LCA[321:707] LCA+BT2: systemHasBluetooth exit - controller = 0x7f88bc856050
Jul 28 04:00:19 localhost LCA[321]: Using keyboard layout 0
Jul 28 04:00:19 localhost Unknown[322]: Keyboard Layouts: duplicate keyboard layout identifier -16899.
Jul 28 04:00:19 localhost Unknown[322]: Keyboard Layouts: keyboard layout identifier -16899 has been replaced with -28673.
Jul 28 04:00:19 localhost Unknown[322]: Keyboard Layouts: duplicate keyboard layout identifier -16900.
Jul 28 04:00:19 localhost Unknown[322]: Keyboard Layouts: keyboard layout identifier -16900 has been replaced with -28674.
Jul 28 04:00:19 localhost LCA[321]: Found primary language hint "en"
Jul 28 04:00:20 localhost LCA[321]: Using keyboard layout 0
Jul 28 04:00:20 localhost LCA[321]: Found primary language hint "en"
Jul 28 04:00:20 localhost LCA[321]: Using keyboard layout 0
Jul 28 04:00:20 localhost LCA[321]: Found primary language hint "en"
Jul 28 04:00:20 localhost LCA[321]: Launching the Installer using language code "English"
Jul 28 04:00:21 localhost Unknown[322]: 2012-07-28 04:00:21.159 OS X Installer[345:707] NSSoftLinking - The Librarian framework's library couldn't be loaded from (null).
Jul 28 04:00:21 localhost Unknown[322]: 2012-07-28 04:00:21.160 OS X Installer[345:707] NSSoftLinking - The function 'LBCurrentProcessHasUbiquityContainer' can't be found in the Librarian framework.
Jul 28 04:00:21 localhost OSInstaller[345]: OS X Installer application started
Jul 28 04:00:21 localhost OSInstaller[345]: 1 display(s) found.
Jul 28 04:00:21 localhost OSInstaller[345]: Display[1] is NOT using OpenGL acceleration.
Jul 28 04:00:21 localhost OSInstaller[345]: @(#)PROGRAM:Install  PROJECT:Install-729
Jul 28 04:00:21 localhost OSInstaller[345]: @(#)PROGRAM:OS X Installer  PROJECT:OSInstaller-419
Jul 28 04:00:21 localhost OSInstaller[345]: Hardware: MacBookPro8,2 @ 2.00 GHz (x 8), 4096 MB RAM
Jul 28 04:00:21 localhost OSInstaller[345]: Running OS Build: Mac OS X 10.8 (12A269)
Jul 28 04:00:21 localhost OSInstaller[345]: Env: DYLD_NO_FIX_PREBINDING=1
Jul 28 04:00:21 localhost OSInstaller[345]: Env: __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x0:0:0
Jul 28 04:00:21 localhost OSInstaller[345]: Env: PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
Jul 28 04:00:21 localhost OSInstaller[345]: Env: PWD=/
Jul 28 04:00:21 localhost OSInstaller[345]: Env: SHLVL=1
Jul 28 04:00:21 localhost OSInstaller[345]: Env: __OSINSTALL_ENVIRONMENT=1
Jul 28 04:00:21 localhost OSInstaller[345]: Env: CI_DEFAULT_OPENCL_USAGE=0
Jul 28 04:00:21 localhost OSInstaller[345]: Env: OS_INSTALL=1
Jul 28 04:00:21 localhost OSInstaller[345]: Env: _=/System/Installation/CDIS/LCA.app/Contents/MacOS/LCA
Jul 28 04:00:21 localhost OSInstaller[345]: Using product PKSecureNetEnabledProduct <file://localhost/Volumes/Mac%20OSX/OS%20X%20Install%20Data/> at distance 5
Jul 28 04:00:21 localhost OSInstaller[345]: Ignoring stale automation file /Volumes/Mac OSX/OS X Install Data/minstallconfig.xml (time since IA = 88810.853148)
Jul 28 04:00:21 localhost OSInstaller[345]: Couldn't find OS X (Server) install data.
Jul 28 04:00:23 localhost configd[112]: subnet_route_if_index: can't get interface name
Jul 28 04:00:25 localhost Unknown[322]: 2012-07-28 04:00:25.920 OS X Installer[345:707] *** WARNING: -[NSImage compositeToPoint:fromRect:operation:] is deprecated in MacOSX 10.8 and later. Please use -[NSImage drawAtPoint:fromRect:operation:fraction:] instead.
Jul 28 04:00:25 localhost OSInstaller[345]: Can not connect to /var/run/systemkeychaincheck.socket: No such file or directory
Jul 28 04:00:26 localhost Unknown[322]: Keyboard Layouts: duplicate keyboard layout identifier -16899.
Jul 28 04:00:26 localhost Unknown[322]: Keyboard Layouts: keyboard layout identifier -16899 has been replaced with -28673.
Jul 28 04:00:26 localhost Unknown[322]: Keyboard Layouts: duplicate keyboard layout identifier -16900.
Jul 28 04:00:26 localhost Unknown[322]: Keyboard Layouts: keyboard layout identifier -16900 has been replaced with -28674.
Jul 28 04:00:52 localhost Unknown[322]: 2012-07-28 04:00 OS X Installer[345] (CarbonCore.framework) FSEventStreamStart: ERROR: FSEvents_connect() => Unknown service name (1102)
Jul 28 04:00:52 localhost OSInstaller[345]: Connection to NetworkBrowserAgent became invalid
Jul 28 04:00:52 localhost OSInstaller[345]: Connection to NetworkBrowserAgent became invalid
Jul 28 04:00:52 localhost OSInstaller[345]: Connection to NetworkBrowserAgent became invalid
Jul 28 04:00:52 localhost OSInstaller[345]: Folder Manager is being asked to create a folder (docs) while running as uid 0
Jul 28 04:00:52 localhost OSInstaller[345]: Folder Manager is being asked to create a folder (docs) while running as uid 0
Jul 28 04:00:52 localhost Unknown[322]: 2012-07-28 04:00:52.417 OS X Installer[345:707] Invalid URL passed to an open/save panel: '(null)'.  Using 'file://localhost/' instead.
Jul 28 04:00:54 localhost Unknown[322]: 2012-07-28 04:00:54.870 OS X Installer[345:707] *** WARNING: -[NSImage compositeToPoint:operation:] is deprecated in MacOSX 10.8 and later. Please use -[NSImage drawAtPoint:fromRect:operation:fraction:] instead.
Jul 28 04:01:03 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: 323.1 - Client: coreservicesd, UID: 0, EUID: 0, GID: 0, EGID: 0
Jul 28 04:01:03 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: 323.1 - ODNodeCreateWithNameAndOptions request, SessionID: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, Name: /Local/Default, Options: 0x0
Jul 28 04:01:03 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: 323.1 - loading configuration for '/Local' from '/System/Library/OpenDirectory/Configurations/Local.plist'
Jul 28 04:01:03 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: Loaded bundle at path '/System/Library/OpenDirectory/Modules/PlistFile.bundle'
Jul 28 04:01:03 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: 323.1 - unable to find authentication module 'ConfigurationProfiles'
Jul 28 04:01:03 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: 323.1 - unable to find service discovery callback for module 'PlistFile'
Jul 28 04:01:03 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: Registering for network changes
Jul 28 04:01:03 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: Registered subnode with name '/Local/Default'
Jul 28 04:01:03 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: 101.3 - Block: nodestate '/Local'
Jul 28 04:01:03 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: 323.1.2 - Block: nodestate '/Local/Default'
Jul 28 04:01:03 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: failed to open local node for internal record copy
Jul 28 04:01:03 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: Registering for power changes
Jul 28 04:01:03 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: 101.3 - nodestate - flagging '/Local' online
Jul 28 04:01:03 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: 101.3 - Block completed
Jul 28 04:01:03 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: Registering for network power changes
Jul 28 04:01:03 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: 323.1.2, Module: PlistFile - Node is 10.7 or later
Jul 28 04:01:03 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: 323.1.2 - nodestate - flagging '/Local/Default' online
Jul 28 04:01:03 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: 323.1.2 - Block completed
Jul 28 04:01:03 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: 323.1, Node: /Local/Default - node assigned UUID - E85B297F-543A-4F72-8203-74E9FC90D411
Jul 28 04:01:03 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: 323.1, Node: /Local/Default - ODNodeCreateWithNameAndOptions completed
Jul 28 04:01:03 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: 323.4 - Client: coreservicesd, UID: 0, EUID: 0, GID: 0, EGID: 0
Jul 28 04:01:03 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: 323.4 - ODQueryCreateWithNode request, NodeID: E85B297F-543A-4F72-8203-74E9FC90D411, RecordType(s): dsRecTypeNative:config, Attribute: dsAttrTypeStandard:RecordName, MatchType: EqualTo, Equality: CaseExact, Value(s): SharePoints, Requested Attributes: dsAttributesAll, Max Results: 1
Jul 28 04:01:03 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: 323.4, Node: /Local/Default, Module: PlistFile - client is using a native record type 'config' which is not portable
Jul 28 04:01:03 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: 323.4, Node: /Local/Default, Module: PlistFile - client is using a native record type 'config' which is not portable
Jul 28 04:01:03 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: 323.4, Node: /Local/Default, Module: PlistFile - ODQueryCreateWithNode completed
Jul 28 04:01:03 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: 323.5 - Client: coreservicesd, UID: 0, EUID: 0, GID: 0, EGID: 0
Jul 28 04:01:03 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: 323.5 - ODNodeCreateRecord request, NodeID: E85B297F-543A-4F72-8203-74E9FC90D411, RecordType: dsRecTypeNative:config, RecordName: SharePoints, Attributes: <none>
Jul 28 04:01:03 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: 323.5, Node: /Local/Default, Module: PlistFile - client is using a native record type 'config' which is not portable
Jul 28 04:01:03 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: 323.5, Node: /Local/Default, Module: PlistFile - ODNodeCreateRecord completed, delivered 1 result
Jul 28 04:01:03 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: 323.6 - Client: coreservicesd, UID: 0, EUID: 0, GID: 0, EGID: 0
Jul 28 04:01:03 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: 323.6 - ODQueryCreateWithNode request, NodeID: E85B297F-543A-4F72-8203-74E9FC90D411, RecordType(s): dsRecTypeNative:config/SharePoints, Attribute: dsAttrTypeStandard:RecordName, MatchType: Any, Equality: CaseExact, Value(s): dsRecordsAll, Requested Attributes: dsAttrTypeStandard:GeneratedUID,dsAttrTypeNative:ftp_guestaccess,dsAttrTypeNative:smb_name,dsAttrTypeNative:sharepoint_account_uuid,dsAttrTypeNative:smb_createmask,dsAttrTypeNative:sharepoint_version,dsAttrTypeStandard:AppleMetaNodeLocation,dsAttrTypeNative:afp_guestaccess,dsAttrTypeNative:afp_shared,dsAttrTypeStandard:RecordType,dsAttrTypeNative:ftp_shared,dsAttrTypeNative:afp_name,dsAttrTypeNative:smb_oplocks,dsAttrTypeNative:afp_use_parent_owner,dsAttrTypeNative:smb_directorymask,dsAttrTypeStandard:RecordName,dsAttrTypeNative:afp_use_parent_privs,dsAttrTypeNative:smb_guestaccess,dsAttrTypeNative:smb_inherit_permissions,dsAttrTypeStandard:AppleMetaRecordName,dsAttrTypeNative:smb_shared,dsAttrTypeNative:directory_path,dsAttrTypeNative:smb_strictlocking,dsAttrTypeNative:sharepoint_group_id,dsAttrTypeNative:ftp_name, Max Results: 2147483647
Jul 28 04:01:03 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: 323.6, Node: /Local/Default, Module: PlistFile - client is using an old record type 'dsRecTypeNative:config/SharePoints' should be using kODRecordTypeSharePoints
Jul 28 04:01:03 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: 323.6, Node: /Local/Default, Module: PlistFile - client is using an old record type 'dsRecTypeNative:config/SharePoints' should be using kODRecordTypeSharePoints
Jul 28 04:01:03 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: 323.6, Node: /Local/Default, Module: PlistFile - flushing record '/private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/config/SharePoints'
Jul 28 04:01:03 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: Module: PlistFile - ___index_record_block_invoke_0: sqlite3_prepare_v2: 21
Jul 28 04:01:03 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: Module: PlistFile - ___index_record_block_invoke_0: sqlite3_prepare_v2: 21
Jul 28 04:01:03 localhost opendirectoryd[101]: 323.6, Node: /Local/Default, Module: PlistFile - ODQueryCreateWithNode completed
Jul 28 04:01:07 localhost OSInstaller[345]: Connection to NetworkBrowserAgent became invalid
Jul 28 04:01:07 localhost OSInstaller[345]: Connection to NetworkBrowserAgent became invalid
Jul 28 04:01:07 localhost OSInstaller[345]: Connection to NetworkBrowserAgent became invalid
Jul 28 04:01:07 localhost OSInstaller[345]: Folder Manager is being asked to create a folder (docs) while running as uid 0
Jul 28 04:01:07 localhost OSInstaller[345]: Folder Manager is being asked to create a folder (docs) while running as uid 0
```

Comment: Try checking your Console for any relevant log messages. Also, you might have a look in the Startup Disk preference pane and switch that setting around before trying the installer again.

Comment: the installer doesn't start after reboot so i dont get the installer console and when i try to load the installer from a usb disk it just says installation failed try reinstalling as soon as it loads and i checked the startup disk it gives me windows and mac os options and mac osx is selected

Comment: That last bit of information probably need to be added to your question.  Boot camp is involved and that changes the question.

Comment: sorry for that i didnt realize th bootcamp was that big of an issue with installs as i have never had issues with this in the past ill make sure i mention that in the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out the restart issue still unresolved but doesn't really matter at this point as the second part I resolved on my own by doing a PRAM/NVRAM reset (command-option-p-r) at startup after this it installed fine I wish I had thought of that before wiping my Mac OS X partition.