# Upgrade from Mac OS 10.6.8 doesnt work

Tags: upgrade

I have a MacBook Pro on OS 10.6.8 I have tried to upgrade to the current OS. The download appears to work fine, but when I select restart to install, the Mac starts to shut down, then just hangs.

I can only start the Mac again by holding down the on/off switch to turn off, and then turning on again.

What is the solution?

Comment: What year/model macbook pro?

Comment: you might have this http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/57811/55028 problem. Try to reset your PRAM.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the required hardware for the system you want to run? Here is a list of requirements, I shamelessly copied these from [support.apple.com](http://support.apple.com)

### OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard system requirements

To install Snow Leopard for the first time, you must have a Mac with:

- An Intel processor
- An internal or external DVD drive, or DVD or CD Sharing
- At least 1 GB of RAM (additional RAM is recommended)
- A built-in display or a display connected to an Apple-supplied video card supported by your computer
- At least 5 GB of disk space available, or 7 GB of disk space if you install the developer tools

### OS X 10.7 Lion system requirements

To use Lion, make sure your computer has the following:

- An Intel Core 2 Duo, Core i3, Core i5, Core i7, or Xeon processor
- Mac OS X v10.6.6 or later to install via the Mac App Store (v10.6.8 recommended)
- 7 GB of available disk space
- 2 GB of RAM

### OS X 10.8 Mountin Lion system requirements

To install Mountain Lion, you need one of these Macs:

- iMac (Mid 2007 or newer)
- MacBook (Late 2008 Aluminum, or Early 2009 or newer)
- MacBook Pro (Mid/Late 2007 or newer)
- MacBook Air (Late 2008 or newer)
- Mac mini (Early 2009 or newer)
- Mac Pro (Early 2008 or newer)
- Xserve (Early 2009)

Your Mac needs:

- OS X v10.6.8 or OS X Lion already installed
- 2 GB or more of memory
- 8 GB or more of available space

### OS X 10.9 Mavericks system requirements

To install Mavericks, you need one of these Macs:

- iMac (Mid-2007 or later)
- MacBook (13-inch Aluminum, Late 2008), (13-inch, Early 2009 or later)
- MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid-2009 or later),
- MacBook Pro (15-inch or 17-inch, Mid/Late 2007 or later)
- MacBook Air (Late 2008 or later)
- Mac mini (Early 2009 or later)
- Mac Pro (Early 2008 or later)
- Xserve (Early 2009)

Your Mac also needs:

- OS X Mountain Lion, Lion, or Snow Leopard v10.6.8 already installed
- 2 GB or more of memory
- 8 GB or more of available space

### OS X 10.10 Yosemite system requirements

Before you install Yosemite, make sure you have one of these Macs:

- iMac (Mid-2007 or newer)
- MacBook (Late 2008 Aluminum, or Early 2009 or newer)
- MacBook Pro (Mid/Late 2007 or newer)
- MacBook Air (Late 2008 or newer)
- Mac mini (Early 2009 or newer)
- Mac Pro (Early 2008 or newer)
- Xserve (Early 2009)

Your Mac also needs:

- OS X Mavericks, Mountain Lion, Lion, or Snow Leopard v10.6.8, already installed
- 2 GB or more of memory
- 8 GB or more of available disk space